# WPF анимация тормозит другие окна

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Есть основное окно, которое создает немодальное окно через Show(), на котором (немодальном окне) есть ProgressBar с IsIndeterminate="True".

Если перетаскивать **основное** окно мышью, то заметны фризы совпадающие по времени с анимацией, что и понятно, ведь все работает в одном потоке UI.

Но если создать то же самое немодальное окно **в отдельном новом** UI потоке (new Thread() со своим Dispatcher), то вместо ожидаемого "нет фризов" мы получаем еще большие фризы при перетаскивании основного окна.

Почему так? И как с этим бороться?

**update: Подробный пример с размышлениями**

Создаем окно MainWindow и отображаем его Show() (или оно само стартует как Application StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml").
Так у нас получается UI поток в котором работает форма.

Из MainWindow создаем NonModalWindow (и на нем расположен ProgressBar с IsIndeterminate, который и создает нагрузку в виде анимации)

```
var view = new NonModalWindow();
view.Show();
```

Получаем немодальное окно. Начинаем таскать мышью MainWindow и наблюдаем мелкие фризы, потому что NonModalWindow получает тот же UI поток и анимация и таскание обрабатывается одним Dispatcher

Cоздаем то же окно, но иначе - в новом потоке

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var view = new NonModalWindow();
        view.Closed += (sender2, e2) => win.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        view.Show();
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    });

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

у нового окна нет никакой связи с родителем, а также свой поток UI и свой Dispatcher.

Ожидается что фризы исчезнут, ведь анимация прогрессбара работает в своем потоке и первый поток UI и его Dispatcher никак не задевает. Но по факту получаем еще большие фризы.

**update2**: можно даже не таскать. открытие второго окна с прогрессбаром начинает влиять на анимацию первого. Вот если второе окно свернуть, то влияние исчезает. Будто бы используется общий поток, но где?

Comment: а зачем она. что то выполнтяс пока она отрабатывает?

Comment: @Санитариум анимация? ну да, индикация чего то выполняемого. Вопрос ведь в том почему вообще есть влияние если у индикации свой поток выделен

Comment: ну лично тот процесс для которого анимация выполнял асинхронно.то есть весь ui  в основном потоке а долгие операции в Task

Comment: @Санитариум Будьте внимательнее. Во втором случае для второго окна СВОЙ поток UI. И долгие операции тут вообще не причем. Тут окна просто существуют. я поправлю вопрос

Comment: я же пишу Вам. У меня была такая ситуация и я ее решил так как написал. зачем Thread если есть Task

Comment: @Санитариум 1 причем тут task, если речь идет об анимации. Вы может отправить работу в task, но анимация останется в ui потоке. 2 new Thread решает проблему блокировки диалоговыми окнами **всех** окон, а не только родителя

Answer (score 0):

попробую подробнее отпишу тут

Есть 2 окно

там такая размтека для анимации

```
<Button RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="100px" Width="150px" Loaded="FrameworkElement_OnLoaded">
            <Button.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="AnimatedRotateTransform" Angle="0" />
            </Button.RenderTransform>
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedRotateTransform"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" 
                                                 To="360" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

При загрузке окна я стартую долгую операции типа запрос к серверу

```
private void FrameworkElement_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            Thread.Sleep(20000);
            MessageBox.Show("End");

    }
```

и как ожидается анимации нет так как я заблочил ее и через скажет End

может что типа такова

```
private void FrameworkElement_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Run(() => 
            {
                Thread.Sleep(20000);
                MessageBox.Show("End");
            });
        }
```

то у меня отработает анимация и  моя операция и все плавно и хорошо

Я надеюсь верно понял вашу проблему

ну пробните это

```
private async  void RunTask()  
        {  
            textBox1.Text = "Task is going to run";  
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);  
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>  
            {  
                RunningTask();  

            });  

        }  

        private void RunningTask()  
        {  
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>  
            {  
                textBox1.Text = "Dispatcher is working";  
            }));  
        }
```

Comment: Похоже что нет. Похоже вы рассматриваете классическую ситуацию когда какая то пользовательская задача блокирует UI поток и потому следует ее выполнять в отдельном потоке. Мой вопрос абсолютно из другой области. В нем нет пользовательских задач. В  нем только задачи для UI потока. И неожиданное поведение.

Comment: Добавил подробный пример

Comment: хотите обновлять ui по мере выполнения операции

Comment: нет. там крутится IsIndeterminate прогрессбар. Я хочу чтобы анимация из отдельного окна перестала влиять на чужие окна. Может там и обновление UI влиет и если открыть пару тяжелых окон пусть даже без анимации, но с частыми обновлениями, то соседняя форма колом станет. А не должна ведь

Comment: обновлил ответ  3

Comment: а зачем вообще  ui  в другом потоке.  ??

Comment: и снова вы про пользовательскую задачу. Повторюсь, прогрессбар это не пользовательская задача. Это просто контрол с визуальной индикацией. При  IsIndeterminate он просто постоянно гоняет индикатор. и никакой связи с RunningTask не имеет. Да и в моем примере вообще нет никаких тасков. Там просто созданные формы, в которых не происходит никакой пользовательской работы

Comment: ну 2 причины. 1 дать возможность немодальным окнам создавать модальные и не блокироваь все на свете. 2 разгрузить основной поток UI если у нас допустим несколько немодальных тяжелых окон.